# Fast method to check if a Matrix is singular? (non-invertible, det = 0)

Tags: algorithm, matrix, matrix-inverse

What is the fastest algorithm (a link to C or C++ example would be cool) to check if a small square matrix (<16*16 elements) is singular (non-invertible, det = 0) ?

Comment: Probably Gaussian Elimination.

Comment: Not sure if it is the fastest, but the SVD will tell you. If any of the singular values found by the SVD are 0, then your matrix is singular.

Comment: @JustinPeel: LU decomposition will outperform SVD for the determinant, but SVD gives you more info: it tells you "which directions" are singular for the matrix. Anyway, testing if a matrix is numerically singular is best performed by computing (a bound on) its condition number, not by computing a determinant (determinant here is 16-linear, so small errors are raised to the 16th power), so SVD is OK if speed is not a serious issue.

Comment: I think it is a common stackoverflow situation: here's how to do X - is it really what you want to do? Why do you want to find the determinant/if the matrix is invertible? It is possible that you will want the SVD anyway to recover from the situation when the matrix is not invertible, or is almost not invertible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Best way is to compute the [condition number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number) via SVD and check if it is greater than 1 / epsilon, where epsilon is the machine precision.

If you allow false negatives (ie. a matrix is defective, but your algorithm may not detect it), you can use the max(a_ii) / min(a_ii) formula from the Wikipedia article as a proxy for the condition number, but you have to compute the QR decomposition first (the formula applies to triangular matrices): A = QR with R orthogonal, then cond(A) = cond(Q). There are also techniques to compute the condition number of Q with O(N) operations, but there are more complex.

Comment: Using LAPACK we can use DGECON/SGECON for double/single precision general matrices or one of the similar routines for matrices with usable structure (banded, symmetric, etc). This uses LU factorization

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Gaussian elimination. http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/doc/Jama/LUDecomposition.html documents LU decomposition - after constructing the LU decomposition from a matrix you can call a method on it to get the determinant. My guess is that it is at least worth timing this to compare it with any more specialised scheme.

Comment: LU decomposition is *the* standard way to compute determinants. Determinants are just not the standard way to test defectiveness of a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

In R the difference is close, but the qr decomposition wins out. Try the following:

```
    Sig <- matrix(rnorm(16),4,4)
    
    a <- Sys.time()
    for(j in 1:1000){
      out <- svd(Sig)
      cond <- any(out$d < 1e-10)
    }
    Sys.time()-a
    
    a <- Sys.time()
    for(j in 1:1000){
      out <- qr(Sig)
      cond <- out$rank < NROW(Sig)
    }
    Sys.time()-a
```

Answer (score -4):

The *fastest* way is probably to hard code a determinant function for each size matrix you expect to deal with.

Here is some psuedo-code for N=3, but if you check out [The Leibniz formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#n-by-n_matrices) for determinants the pattern should be clear for all N.

```
function is_singular3(matrix) {
    det = matrix[1][1]*matrix[2][2]*matrix[3][3]
        - matrix[1][1]*matrix[2][3]*matrix[3][2]
        - matrix[1][2]*matrix[2][1]*matrix[3][3]
        + matrix[1][2]*matrix[2][3]*matrix[3][1]
        + matrix[1][3]*matrix[2][1]*matrix[3][2]
        - matrix[1][3]*matrix[2][2]*matrix[3][1];

     if(det==0) return true
     else return false
}
```

Comment: An epsilon distance check from zero is in order for floating point matrices.

Comment: He will need a meta-program to generate the hard-code formula.

Comment: For n=16 this may well be quite cumbersome to write.

Comment: -1 For n=15 Leibniz's formula will have 1.3 trillion summands.  This is not a realistic answer.

Comment: -1, the issue is not how to generate the code effectively. The issue is with the general time complexity of the problem.