# remove cells that satisfy a specific condition

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a cell array which each cell is an n-by-n matrix. I want to delete the cells for which `inv(cell{i}'*cell{i})` gives warning that matrix is close to singular.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, removing elements is the easy part. If `C` is your array, removing cells specified by the indices in vector `idx` can be done by:

```
C(idx) = {};
```

Regarding your specific problem, to check if a matrix is "almost" singular or not can be done with [`rcond`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rcond.html) (if the result is close to zero, it's probably singular). To apply it to all cells you can use `cellfun` in the following way:

```
idx = cellfun(@(x)(rcond(x' * x) < 1e-12), C);
```

Adjust the threshold value to your liking. The resulting `idx` is a logical array with `1`s at the location of singular matrices. Use `idx` to remove these elements from `C` as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function that check for your condition:

```
function state = CheckElement(element)

if ([condition])
   state = 1;
else
   state = 0;
end

end
```

then do cellfun on all you cell array elements like the following:

```
indices = cellfun(@CheckElement,myCellArray);
cellArray(indices ) = [];
```

Comment: You don't need the `'UniformOutput', false` part when  computing `indices`. You want indices to be a matrix, not a cell array.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have already defined a `issingular` function defined you can use `cellfun` to get the indices of the cells that contain the matrices you want to remove.

```
c; % cell arry

singularIdx = cellfun((@x) issingular( inv(x' * x)), c);  %' added single quote for SO syntax

cFiltered = c(~singluarIdx);
```

You'll probably need to write your own function to check for singularity, for more information on that see this question: [Fast method to check if a Matrix is singular? (non-invertible, det = 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826816/fast-method-to-check-if-a-matrix-is-singular-non-invertible-det-0)

Comment: The `'` and `*` operators are not defined for cell arrays, so you'll trigger an error for the `c'` and `c' * c` parts. Also, I'm not sure that you actually have to compute `inv`... I think it's the `c'*c` result that can be singular.

Comment: @EitanT, oh yea, I totally messed that up. I actually had to wrap it in a anonymous function to get the desired behavior

Comment: I still think the `inv` is unnecessary.

Comment: @EitanT, yea you're probably right, I was simply echoing the original code from the OP

Comment: At first, I was doing the same thing :)