# Error when multiplying matrices

Tags: r

I'm trying to multiply some matrices and the following error occurs:

```
B <- 2*mcov
B <- cbind(B,c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
B <- cbind(B,t(mrend))
B <- rbind(B, c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0))
B <- rbind(B, ((1 + c(meanNovartis, meanRDS, meanRoche, meanEJ, meanHSBC, 
           meanBayer, meanUnilever, meanGSK, meanSanofi, meanAnheuser, 
           meanSiemens, meanLoreal, meanInnate, 
           meanBT,meanNestle,0,0)^12)-1))
B
c <- matrix(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,(((1+mean(meanRDS))^12))-1),
            nrow=17, ncol=1)
```

And when trying to solve:

```
 x <- solve(B)%*%c
```

This error appears:

> Error in solve.default(B) : Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[17,17] = 0

Comment: Your question has already been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572119/r-solvesystem-is-exactly-singular)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compute the LU factorization of a matrix which has no inverse.  As a result, the `LAPACK` package (which is what R is actually running when you make your call to `solve`) is trying to divide by zero.

The solution to your problem is to either clean up your data if that be the cause, or find another way to obtain your eigenvalues.