# R inverting matrix with solve returning Error

Tags: r, matrix, matrix-inverse

I am studying R programming.

I am trying to inverting matrix. Below is what I have tried.

```
x <- matrix(1:16, 4, 4)
x
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    5    9   13
# [2,]    2    6   10   14
# [3,]    3    7   11   15
# [4,]    4    8   12   16

solve(x)
# Error in solve.default(x) : 
#  Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[3,3] = 0

solve(x) %*% x
# Error in solve.default(x) : 
#  Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[3,3] = 0

x %*% solve(x)
# Error in solve.default(x) : 
#  Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[3,3] = 0
```

I can not understand what 'singular' means. According to this [link](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/solve), it is said that if `solve` does not have second parameter, it inverts first parameter.

I am fully confused, so need some explanation with example would be wonderful.

Comment: Unfortunately for you, you are using a special case with your matrix "x". You would have more luck using a more general case (`x <- matrix(rnorm(16),4,4)`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R solve:system is exactly singular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572119/r-solvesystem-is-exactly-singular)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you compute the `determinant` of the matrix, it is `0`:

```
det(x)
[1] 0
```

By definition, your matrix is not invertible. But before trying to invert a squared matrix, the first instinct should be to study analytically if the matrix can be invertible.

The singular error you get just reflects the matrix is not invertible.

Comment: Thanks. and in additionally, I found solve can invert numeric/logical matrix only. mine was integer matrix :D