# Avoid Lapack routine dges in Mahalanobis distance

Tags: r, lapack, mahalanobis

I get the following error while running the `mahalanobis` distance

```
Error in solve.default(cov, ...) : 
  Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[2,2] = 0
```

This is my code.

```
calibration <- 10
mean <- colMeans(x[1:calibration,])
sx <- cov(x[1:calibration,])
d <- mahalanobis(x[1:calibration,], mean, sx)
```

And this the data

```
1 0.7071068
0 0.0000000
2 1.4142136
2 1.4142136
0 0.0000000
0 0.0000000
2 1.4142136
1 0.7071068
1 0.7071068
0 0.0000000
```

How can I avoid this error?

Comment: What is `calibration`?

Comment: It's value is equal 10

Comment: the problem is not the lapack routine, it is the covariance matrix of your data that is singular, which means the determinant is 0, hence the matrix is not invertible and you cannot calculate the Mahalanobis distance.

Comment: Right, which condition can I insert to avoid this calculation? my script cannot go through this error

Comment: See `try` function. `try(d <- mahalanobis(x[1:calibration,], mean, sx), silent = TRUE)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R solve:system is exactly singular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572119/r-solvesystem-is-exactly-singular)

Comment: @Pascal it works. thanks